# JSS: apply css property twice

Tags: material-ui, jss

```
.fixedLayout {
    // clear epic styles
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: var(--safe-area-inset-bottom) !important;
}
```

Is it possible to make the same with the @material-ui/core/styles?

This is invalid code:

```
const styles = {
  paddingBottom: '0 !important',
  paddingBottom: 'var(--safe-area-inset-bottom) !important',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixedLayout {
    // clear epic styles
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

It will apply last css property to page. In this case, padding-bottom: 10px will be apply on .fixedLayout class

Comment: From CSS perspective all is clear for me. And what about JSS, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to use an array then put each property in its individual object.

```or-tag-here
const styles = {
    fixedLayout: [
        // clear epic styles
        {
            paddingBottom: '0 !important',
        },
        {
            paddingBottom: 'var(--safe-area-inset-bottom) !important',
        }
    ]
};
```